# Modificar método de login para usuário e senha

Tags: suporte, login

Atualmente utilizo o facebook como método de login. Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar para logar utilizando email e senha.

Sei que é possível adicionar novos métodos nesta página, no entanto não achei nada relacionado a adição de email e senha.

[image: Adicionar Credenciais de Login]

Comment: Possível duplicada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5559/3117

Comment: Veja a "NOTA" na página indicada http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5559/sou-cadastrado-aqui-com-o-facebook-posso-vincular-meu-email

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. As pesquisas com as palavras-chave que fiz não me levaram a esta resposta.
No entando, como é possível ver na imagem que postei, não há opção de adicionar credencial stack exchange.